# Python/MongoDB - Update each document with a sample from another collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am working with pymongo and latest mongo db. I try to create random bulk data for a DB test.

In this scenario I want to update every document of one collection:
We have to set one property of each to a random existing ID of another collection, incl. some filters.

In our example we have a collection courses and persons and want to assign one randomly picked person (whom should be a professor) to our course.

Currently I am doing this manually by getting the IDs and updating every single document. Here the raw "slow" query workflow with python:

```
def assign_lektor(vorlesungen):
    for vorlesung in vorlesungen:
       prof_id = db_helper.get_random_prof_by_fak_id(vorlesung['FakultaetID'])
       db_helper.update_document(vorlesung['_id'],"LektorID",prof_id,VORLESUNGEN_COLL)



def get_random_prof_by_fak_id(fakultaet_id):
    collection = client[DATABASE][PERSON_COLL]
    record = list(
        collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"FakultaetID": fakultaet_id, "Art": "Professor"}}, {
                             "$sample": {"size": 1}}])
    )[0]
    return record['_id']
```

This is working fine, but of course it's very slow.
But now we wanted to make the whole thing much more efficient. After hours of trial and error we came to this approach, with which we now only have to make one request per course:

```
def assign_random_lector(vorlesung):
    collection = client[DATABASE][VORLESUNGEN_COLL]
    record = collection.aggregate([
        {"$match" : {"_id" : vorlesung['_id']}},
        {"$lookup": {
            "from": "Person",
            "pipeline": [
                    {"$match": {"Art" : "Professor","FakultaetID": vorlesung['FakultaetID']}},
                    {"$sample" : {"size" : 1}},
                    {"$project" : {"_id":1}}
            ],
            "as": "random_sample"
        }},
        {"$set" : {"LektorID" : {"$first": "$random_sample._id"}}},
        {"$project" : {"random_sample" : 0}},
        {"$merge" : {
            "into" : "Vorlesungen",
            "on" : "_id",
            "whenMatched" : "replace",
            "whenNotMatched" : "discard"
        }}
    ])
```

How can you solve this task with one efficient query? Is there any way to iterate with the cursor over the collection and apply this "aggregation" shown above for every element at once.
The whole query should run on the database, to minimize the I/O. We want to avoid any unnecessary client side logic like for loops.

Comment: One thing would speed up is to create an index in the $lookup>$match. `db.col.createIndex({Art:1, FakultaetID:1})`

Comment: we have already indexed. That is not the point either. Multithreading would also speed it up. But we are looking for this one specific and efficient query that just performs the whole operations on the database.

Comment: good luck then.

Comment: Hey @Chikko, If you got success in this assignment of yours. Please share the solution.

Comment: @Lostman we couldn't find a working solution